# Change output filename in setup.py (distutils.extension)

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py, distutils, distutils2

Here's my **setup.py**

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

wrapper = Extension(
    name="libwrapper",
    ...
)
setup(
    name="libwrapper",
    ext_modules=cythonize([wrapper])
)
```

When I run `python3 setup.py build_ext` the output file is called `libwrapper.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, but I want to name it only `libwrapper.so`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code. `sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX')` returns platform-specific suffix which can be removed from the final filename by subclassing `build_ext` and overriding `get_ext_filename`.

```py
from distutils import sysconfig
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from distutils.core import setup
import os

class NoSuffixBuilder(build_ext):
    def get_ext_filename(self, ext_name):
        filename = super().get_ext_filename(ext_name)
        suffix = sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX')
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        return filename.replace(suffix, "") + ext


setup(
    ....
    cmdclass={"build_ext": NoSuffixBuilder},
)
```

Final filename will be `test.so`

Comment: Can you extend my `setup.py` file with your suggestion? It's not clear how to do it.

Comment: Just add `NoSuffixBuilder` to your `setup.py` file and  `cmdclass=...` to your `setup` function and build the extension using `python setup.py build_ext`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/cython/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    class NoSuffixBuilder(build_ext):
NameError: name 'build_ext' is not defined